# IntelliJ IDEA - Get Cannot resolve method 'isBlank' in 'String' but works fine in STS

Tags: java, intellij-idea, spring-tool-suite

I recently moved my Java project from Spring Tools IDE to IntelliJ, but I'm getting an error that I'm not having in STS : "Cannot resolve method 'isBlank' in 'String' " Which is more, in Spring Tools the test is running successfully.  I tried rebuild the pom file but still having the error.

The portion of code I'm using is this:

```
if (uploadedPDFName == null || uploadedPDFName.isBlank()) {
    //do something
}
```

I'm capturing file name in a string variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is about your JDK version,if you have an old version like JDK 8 or JDK 7 ...you will have an error when using isBlank() because String::isBlank() was introduced in java 11.
You Can check by typing :java --version in a terminal if you have an old version,you Can just use isEmpty().

Answer (score 2):

[String::isBlank](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isBlank()) was introduced in Java 11. You probably have IntelliJ configured to use some older Java version (most likely Java 8). I recommend using some other code alternative as Java 11 is not yet widely supported.

For example:

```java
if (uploadedPDFName == null || uploadedPDFName.trim().length() == 0)
```

or

```java
if (uploadedPDFName == null || uploadedPDFName.chars().allMatch(Character::isWhitespace))
```

In case you are only concerned of checking if it is empty use [String::isEmpty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty--). However, isBlank returns true if the String has whitespaces, isEmpty does not.

Comment: Actually you guys are very right about JDK version, I probably have STS with version 11 and didn't realize.  I'm pretty sure that   I have JDK 8 with IntelliJ so I solved using one of your advices.  Thank you all.

Comment: @Jillbarvi Glad we could help. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, I'm a newbie around here.

Comment: @Jillbarvi Just click at the checkmark at the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would check that the IntelliJ is set up to be using at least Java 11, as that is when `isBlank()` was introduced. You could also try `isEmpty()` as well but the JDK version is my guess as to what's causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `pom.xml` Then change Java version to above or equal to 16 and then `Maven -> Update`